# Cassandra: Simplest way to backup data from one machine and restore on a fresh machine

Tags: cassandra

I have cassandra running on a single machine. I need to backup a particular keyspace from there and setup the same schema with all the data on my local machine.

I understand that I can run the `nodetool snapshot` command take the point in time snapshot of the keyspace.

But from the documentation, I could understand that it requires the schema to exist. Is there not any command which can take the backup with the schema and restore it to another machine? The data is very small, hardly a few MBs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same version of Cassandra on the single machine and on your local machine, there is a brute force solution (**not to be used in production**):copy all the folder $CASSANDRA_HOME/data (or sometimes /var/lib/cassandra/data) from one machine to another ...

Comment: I just tried this and didn't have any luck. Here is what I did... https://gist.github.com/chrowe/36e4271bc4c5a563db9e7bdace69aa46